# Adding total priority to linux scheduling

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have an assignment to add total priority to linux process scheduling and add a syscall so that each process that calls this syscall, gets total priority. (total priority means that as long as there is a process with toal priority in the system, it will always be chosen to run).

To implements this, I have added a new field named `has_abs_prio` to `task_struct`:

```
...

#if defined(CONFIG_BCACHE) || defined(CONFIG_BCACHE_MODULE)
    unsigned int    sequential_io;
    unsigned int    sequential_io_avg;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_ATOMIC_SLEEP
    unsigned long   task_state_change;
#endif
    int pagefault_disabled;
    int has_abs_priority;   //<-----------------------------
/* CPU-specific state of this task */
    struct thread_struct thread;
/*
 * WARNING: on x86, 'thread_struct' contains a variable-sized
 * structure.  It *MUST* be at the end of 'task_struct'.
 *
 * Do not put anything below here!
 */
};
```

I have also modified the `INIT_TASK` macro to initialize this value with 0.

I have modified the `pick_next_task` function in `sched/core.c` as such:

```
static inline struct task_struct *
pick_next_task(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *prev)
{
    const struct sched_class *class = &fair_sched_class;
    struct task_struct *p;
    if (prev->has_abs_priority){
         return prev;
    }

    ...
```

(I know that this is not exactly what the assignment asked, because for this to work, the process must be chosen once and thereafter it has absolute priority but I figured it was close enough. )

and added a syscall that basically does this:

```
current->has_abs_priority = 1;
```

But whenever I call the syscall, the system crashes. I think the problem must be in the modification to pick_next_task because if I comment `return prev;` in `pick_next_task` no crash happens. Also I'm running this on a VirtualBox VM and I don't know how to capture the crash output (shift+pageup doesn't work)
[but here is a screenshot of the final part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO6DI.png) .

Also if it helps, the kernel version is 4.2.5 and the OS is archlinux.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Why don't you just use SCHED_FIFO priority 99?